# Failed to set MokListRT: out of Resources : import_mok_state()

Tags: boot, uefi, grub-efi, secure-boot, moklistrt

I'm facing a huge problem with MOK manager. After a install Ubuntu 19.10, with third party drivers install enabled, I rebooted the system. On boot, MOK manager was launched normally, but accidentally I pressed <kbd>Esc</kbd>, cancelling the MOK enrollment. Now, when I try to boot on Ubuntu, a message is show (see image or text below*, please). The problem occur even when I try to boot on live USB!

I've tried several "solutions" found search on internet, but none worked.

I'm locked, unable to use Ubuntu in any ways! It's sad!

I use a Samsung X23 noteboot/laptop.

> Failed to set MokListRT: out of Resources. Something has gone seriously wrong: import_mok_state() failed : Out of Resources

[image: photo of the error]

My computer works fine with Windows 10 and hardware is fine too. I've downloaded and created USB live more than three times, with different Linux distribution, but none works.

What I already tried:

- Disable Secure Boot
- Add entry boot
- Use CSM BIOS
- Try to install again a linux distribuition
- Deleted Linux partitions
- Try to use live USB on UEFI mode
  All of this took me to the same place, the error message.

Only one thing worked, that is use live USB on CSM mode. I installed Ubuntu CSM but I can't boot on, same thing as EFI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this problem.

1. Create a Live USB/CD of Ubuntu 17.10.
2. Boot this USB/CD in UEFI mode (the problem doesn't happen with this version).
3. Open terminal and use this command: `sudo mokutil --reset`.
4. Try to boot with the system you want to install.
5. If you get this another error "Failed to open \EFI\BOOT\mmx64.efi", change the file name of "`grubx64.efi`" to "`mmx64.efi`" (located on `/efi/boot` on USB/CD).
6. Boot again and you will see no errors (I hope so).

Comment: This solution is working for me