# Ubuntu 20.04.5 live USB flash fails to boot (Failed to set MokListRT: Out of Resources) on 2011 Dell Optiplex 990

Tags: boot, live-usb, startup-disk-creator, startup-disk, moklistrt

Had Ubuntu 18.04 Desktop on a Dell Optiplex 990.  Tried to upgrade it to 20.04 over the network but that had periodic errors and eventually failed.  Could get GUI login screen but could not login.  After following steps such as in   https://ostechnix.com/how-to-fix-broken-ubuntu-os-without-reinstalling-it/  (which ran with errors) I could login, but video was limited to 800x600, it couldn't recognize my display, and updates failed because of unmet dependencies.  In this report I'm skipping the details of those errors because I decided to try to reinstall from scratch.

So, the problem is every Ubuntu 20.04.5 live USB flash drive I've made with Startup Disk Creator cannot be booted.  I've made the flash drives on another Ubuntu 20.04 system, an Ubuntu 18.04.5 system, and an Ubuntu 16.04 system (the later 2 being booted from old bootable flash drives I still have).  I get the error "Failed to Set MokListRT: Out of resources."
[Error message:  Failed to Set MokListRT: Out of resources](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gIzy2.png)

Researched that issue, e.g.:
[Failed to set MokListRT: out of Resources : import_mok_state()](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231992/failed-to-set-moklistrt-out-of-resources-import-mok-state#1247574)
[Ubuntu 20.04 Failed to Set MokListRT: Invalid Parameter](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1279602/ubuntu-20-04-failed-to-set-moklistrt-invalid-parameter)
and several people who have gotten a similar error after updating their Mac or Intel laptop with Ubuntu suggest fixing it by either:

1. overwriting the shim executeable with a copy of the grub executeable
   (e.g. cd /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu, cp grubx64.efi shimx64.efi).  But the
   problem with this, after searching, is shimx64.efi doesn't exist on
   the live flash, except perhaps inside the shim...deb package,

OR

2. overwriting mmx64.efi with grubx64.efi (which on the live flash are
   both in /EFI/BOOT/).   I attempted the later but it turned out that
   since the flash drive has an ISO9660 file system, it's read only and
   can't be mounted rw, so I can't "cp grubx64.efi mmx64.efi".

So, again, the problem is every Ubuntu 20.04.5 live USB flash drive I've made with Startup Disk Creator cannot boot on my 2011 Dell Optiplex 990, or my 2011 Dell Latitude E6420.  Both of these have the latest BIOS, and have GPT disks so I boot in UEFI mode (since, from recalling upgrade difficulties ~2 years ago, I think if I boot the live flash in MBR mode but install on a GPT disk, it doesn't work).  There is no secure boot setting in BIOS.  FYI I have Ubuntu and Windows 10 installed on the boot disk.  FYI I have used at least 2 different flash drives, have formatted them as GPT before running Startup Disk Creator, but after Startup Disk Creator is finished they appear (in the Disks utility) as MBR not GPT.  Also FYI per this article    https://web.sas.upenn.edu/jasonrw/2016/04/07/uefi-and-a-dell-optiplex-990/   Dell 990s support either BIOS/MBR or UEFI, but not both simultaneously (no UEFI-CSM compatibility mode).

Comment: I don't know your issue, but I used dell optiplex 980s & 990s in some QA & had no issues with them (*my primary box was a 960 until it's PSU died a few months back*), thus it reads to me like all your ISOs were either corrupt (*did you verify they were valid?*) or your write of ISO to media is invalid (*did you use another working box to verify the ISO write? given you can't boot it on those box*). You can write ISOs in many ways, some make it only boot in some environments but not others; but if written correctly as a *clone* it'll boot in all (*excluding firmware bugs*)

Comment: FYI:  Some of your details are incorrect; you can boot in *legacy* mode & install to GPT, or boot in uEFI & boot write to a legacy MBR type partition table. The operator (*& how ISO is written*) can control/limit this though; all Ubuntu releases of Desktop install to *legacy* & don't require ESP either (*though its creation is a default for some ISOs*).  You didn't specify what ISO though; only it was 20.04.5 (of which there are many; server, desktop, for many architectures & flavors etc).

Answer (score 1):

I have several thoughts on this....

First, I recommend against installing Ubuntu 20.04 at this time. Ubuntu 22.04 is the current LTS release. Ubuntu 22.04 will be supported for longer than 20.04, and 22.04 includes more up-to-date packages. That said, I doubt if using Ubuntu 22.04 would help you fix your problem; this is more a matter of general advice.

Second, the error message you're seeing suggests that your computer's NVRAM storage may be either full or so fragmented that Shim can't create a new variable. You might be able to improve matters a bit by removing redundant or unwanted EFI boot variables. The easiest way for you to do this is probably to boot my [rEFInd boot manager](https://rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html); there's a USB flash drive image available that should boot directly (that image does not use Shim, which also means that you'll have to disable Secure Boot to boot it). Once in rEFInd, there's a second-row option to adjust NVRAM-based boot entries. You should be able to use that to delete unwanted boot entries. Be careful, though; delete only options that you're *certain* are unnecessary or redundant! Ultimately, though, I suspect that the problem is Secure Boot db and dbx keys, and/or Shim MOKs. Your firmware probably has an option to reset the Secure Boot db and dbx keys to their defaults, but precisely how varies from one computer to another. I couldn't find instructions on doing this for your Dell, but I did find [this article](https://techlibrary.hpe.com/docs/iss/proliant-gen10-uefi/GUID-32324685-47B3-4BE5-A43E-737F3A36BA18.html) about how to do it on an HP computer. Maybe that'll be helpful, or at least point you in the right direction. It's also conceivable that your firmware includes an option to reset everything to factory defaults, which *might* (or might not) clear the NVRAM of all the variables it's acquired over time. Note, however, that Secure Boot db and dbx keys exist for a reason, and deleting them can cause security problems. If you can't boot your computer, though, that can be an even bigger problem, so you may have little choice but to accept an increased security risk and either make do with a slimmer dbx or disable Secure Boot entirely.

Concerning the fact that `shimx64.efi` doesn't exist on the live image, that's because it has a different name. Removable media (CD-Rs, USB flash drives, etc.) boot using the *fallback filename* of `EFI\BOOT\bootx64.efi`; `shimx64.efi` is renamed to that filename on them. On an Ubuntu installer, `EFI\BOOT\bootx64.efi` (Shim) then launches `grubx64.efi` in the same directory; so with Secure Boot disabled, you can launch GRUB directly by renaming `grubx64.efi` to `bootx64.efi`. Note, however, that if this works, the installer with put Shim on the hard disk (as `EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi`), so you'll need to create a non-Shim boot path (using `efibootmgr`; see [here](https://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/installation.html) for details) or rename `grubx64.efi` to `shimx64.efi` in that directory. (The former is the better option, if it works....) A further complication is that, given the nature of your problem, the installer might not be able to create a new boot entry, so rebooting after the install might fail. This leads back to the above solution -- cleaning up the (presumably) over-full NVRAM.

Finally, as @guiverc notes, switching the computer to boot in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode is an option. Most UEFI-based PCs (those made since 2011 or so) are UEFI-based, but most of them also include a Compatibility Support Module (CSM), which enables them to boot legacy BIOS OSes. Hence, the three terms *BIOS*, *CSM*, and *legacy* are more-or-less interchangeable in this context. All three rely on the CSM *compatibility layer* of the UEFI, so the computer remains UEFI-based when booting a BIOS-mode OS; but any given OS installation will be one or the other. Thus, you can probably work around these problems by doing a BIOS-mode install of Ubuntu. The trick is forcing the computer to boot in BIOS mode rather than in EFI mode. This is most easily accomplished by removing the EFI-mode boot loaders, which are files in the `EFI` directory on the boot medium. Whatever tool you used to create the boot medium will have to have included a BIOS-mode boot loader, too. Note also that this approach works best if the computer is to boot *ONLY* BIOS-mode OSes, because GRUB 2 can't switch between boot modes. That is, the BIOS-mode GRUB 2 can launch only BIOS-mode OSes, and the EFI-mode GRUB 2 can launch only EFI-mode OSes. Thus, if you want to dual-boot an existing EFI-mode Windows alongside Ubuntu, it's best to stick with an EFI-mode Ubuntu installation, if at all possible. If you must mix boot modes, then my [rEFInd boot manager](https://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) can do the trick, but you'll need to enable support on the `scanfor` line in its `refind.conf` file. Using rEFInd in your case has the disadvantage that you'd still need to create an EFI boot entry for it, and that might not be possible, given the overcrowded state of your NVRAM. Also, no matter how you do it, booting in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode means giving up the protections of Secure Boot, so this approach is not preferable to deleting the dbx from a security point of view.

So in sum, there are a number of possible solutions and workarounds to your problem, but ultimately, my suspicion is that your best option is to clean up what I suspect is an overcrowded NVRAM.

Comment: I used rEFInd' "Manage EFI boot order" to see I had 11 boot entries (7 legacy/MBR and 4 EFI); I deleted 4 of the legacy entries but after reboot they unfortunately came back.  I disabled them in BIOS and deleted them again, but they came back again.
I think my next step to try to free up NVRAM storage is to remove the "CMOS battery" as in https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-us/000124377/how-to-perform-a-bios-or-cmos-reset-and-clear-the-nvram-on-dell-systems    After resetting BIOS it should see the UEFI boot devices again because it reads that info off the storage devices, correct?

Comment: I'll defer to Dell's documentation on how to reset the NVRAM to factory defaults. If successful, this will leave the computer booting through the fallback filename (`EFI\BOOT\bootx64.efi` on the ESP), which might or might not be present or boot in the way you expect. You may want to check this before doing anything. (It'd be `/boot/efi/EFI/BOOT/bootx64.efi` in Ubuntu. Be aware that case is irrelevant on the ESP itself.)

Comment: I had too much material to fit in a comment, and also comments won't accept images, so I posted an answer to my own question(s)/problem(s).

Answer (score 0):

**1.**  I completed and fixed my broken upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04 desktop by **first disabling SAV Sophos Anti Virus**

`sudo /opt/sophos-av/bin/savdctl disable`

Apparently the anti-virus interferes with *some*, but not most, of the updates!  (boy did I feel dumb!)
Then I ran the commands in https://ostechnix.com/how-to-fix-broken-ubuntu-os-without-reinstalling-it/  namely:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend
sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/lock

sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt clean
sudo apt update --fix-missing
sudo apt install -f

sudo dpkg --configure -a 
sudo apt upgrade 
sudo apt dist-upgrade 
sudo reboot
```

**2a.**  Regarding the issue of Startup Disk Creator making Ubuntu 20.04 desktop USB flash drives that won't boot on my Dell Optiplex 990, that is not fixed.  However as a workaround I discovered that USB flash with:

- Ubuntu 18.04.5 boots with no errors
- Ubuntu 18.04.6 gets the MokListRT Out of Resources error, but continues to "boot since secure mode is disabled":
  [Fig 1. Ubuntu 18.04.6 live USB flash errors but still boots on Dell 990](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XxNKm.png)
- Ubuntu 20.04.5 gets the MokListRT error and fails to boot

*So I'd recommend to someone getting this error on old hardware that does not support Secure Boot, to install Ubuntu 18.04.6 or earlier, and then upgrade over the net.*

**2b.**  To try and free up space in NVRAM as Rod Smith suggested, I used rEFInd boot manager to delete unnecessary boot entries, but my Dell Optiplex 990 kept adding the Legacy boot entries back in:

[Fig 2. Initial boot entries and shown by rEFInd, including unnecessary Legacy entries (diskette drive doesn't even exist!)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yU7gA.png)

[Fig 3. After 4 Legacy boot entries deleted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDnpM.png)

[Fig 4. ...But after reboot my Dell 990 BIOS kept putting unnecessary Legacy boot entries back in.  Note the higher numbers on the left hand side 1A 1B 1C](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BANZ8.png)

And then to clear CMOS NVRAM I followed instructions in https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-us/000124377/how-to-perform-a-bios-or-cmos-reset-and-clear-the-nvram-on-dell-systems  by removing the battery, moving the motherboard jumper to RTCRST (which on a Dell Optiplex 990 mini-tower is hidden under the SATA connectors), and -- after taking pictures of my UEFI boot entries in BIOS -- using BIOS Load defaults.  But, you guessed it, my Dell Optiplex 990 kept adding the Legacy boot entries back in:
[Fig 4.  Final boot entries after BIOS NVRAM cleared many times](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3uzUV.jpg)

So then I researched the update dependencies problem and discovered that disabling anti-virus is necessary to allow SOME updates to work, as described above.

Comment: Most EFIs will add back certain EFI boot entries, such as those that enter the firmware setup utility or that enable BIOS/CSM/legacy-mode boots, if you delete them. This is normal and expected, although the details vary from one firmware implementation to another. Sometimes you can permanently remove certain entries by disabling the relevant firmware features -- for instance, you may be able to remove BIOS/CSM/legacy boot options by disabling the CSM in the firmware.